# Fabric.js doesn't maintain group when exporting/importing JSON

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

So I have another issue with Fabric.js that's once again probably down to my own ignorance.

Imagine using free draw to scribble some line paths on to a canvas. When finished, we disable free draw and at this point I want to take all the objects drawn and group them in to a single entity.

I've created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibbaldl/jkydfke9/) that shows the grouping stage.

```
var grp=new fabric.Group();

canvas.getObjects().map(function(o){
    if(o.type=="path"){
        o.hasControls=o.hasBorders=false;
        grp.addWithUpdate(o);
        //canvas.clear(); // this seems to break grouping
    }
});
canvas.add(grp);
canvas._activeObject = null;
canvas.setActiveGroup(grp.setCoords()).renderAll();
```

This appears to work well enough (even if the paths themselves appear to darken once the group has been created).

I now want to export this to JSON, save at a DB, and in the future reload and replicate the whole layout.

In the fiddle above I reproduce this sort of behaviour by first saving the canvas to JSON after the group has been created, and then attempt to reload it.

As you'll see, the reload itself works fine and the positioning is good but the item that was previously grouped has been loaded in to it's constituent parts, rather than being maintained as a group.

Am I doing something dumb here?

Thanks for any help!